# SQL Server Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table named `tblMastTestElement`

```
cTestCode    |  cElementCode
24HCRECLE    |  CRE
CALCRECLE    |  CRE
CALEXR       |  CRE
CRE          |  CRE
CRECLE       |  CRE
EGFR         |  CRE
EGFR         |  EG
```

I need a query to return EGFR as testcode  which has the elements CRE And EG only

something like this

```
Select cTestCode
from tblMastTestElement
where cElementCode IN('CRE' And 'EG')
```

Comment: The problem here is you need to test for two records. You can do a self-join where each instance of the table test for each elment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return the cTestCode that have `cElementCode` for **both** 'CRE' and 'EG' (not **either**) you can use.

```
SELECT cTestCode
FROM   tblMastTestElement
WHERE  cElementCode IN ( 'CRE', 'EG' )
GROUP  BY cTestCode
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cElementCode) = 2
```

Comment: @faiz - Yes there are. You must be taking our code and not implementing it correctly. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edd335/3

Comment: Sorry Martin, Yes it returned , thank a lot you have saved me a lot of time. Last night I was falling sleep it was 1.30 AM here in Sri Lanka

Answer (score 2):

```
Select distinct t1.cTestCode
from tblMastTestElement t1
join tblMastTestElement t2 on t2.cTestCode = t1.cTestCode
where t1.cElementCode = 'EG'
and t2.cElementCode = 'CRE'
```

Comment: @faiz - there should be once you fix the error with the ambiguous cTestCode column. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edd335/2

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. If I have more free time I can acid test mine and yours to check performance. Your answer is ingenious by the way ;)

Comment: Martin I fixed the ambiguous cTestCode, still no records returned, thanks anyway

Comment: @faiz - So you aren't running it against the data you show in the question then.

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
Select t1.cTestCode
from tblMastTestElement t1
where t1.cElementCode = 'CRE'
AND EXISTS (
    Select 1
    from tblMastTestElement t2
    where t2.cElementCode = 'EG'
    AND t1.cTestCode = t2.cTestCode)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is nowhere near as efficient as Martin Smith's answer, but if you insist that doesn't work, we might as well be comprehensive in solutions:

```
SELECT cTestCode FROM tblMastTestElement WHERE cElementCode = 'CRE'
INTERSECT
SELECT cTestCode FROM tblMastTestElement WHERE cElementCode = 'EG'
```

If that doesn't work, run this:

```
SELECT cTestCode, cElementCode
FROM tblMastTestElement 
WHERE cTestCode = 'EGFR'
    AND cElementCode IN ('CRE','EG');
```

If *that* doesn't return two rows, then your data are bad.  Note that that query isn't supposed to be an answer, it's just to prove out if your data are bad.